# How to change the automatic switching of panes into default setting in Rstudio

Tags: plot, console, rstudio, pane

In RStudio, I'm experiencing an issue where the source, console, and plot panes are switching automatically. For instance, whenever I plot something in R, the plot window pops up automatically and covers my entire screen, obscuring the source code (coding terminal). It becomes bothersome having to continuously press "shift+enter" to return from the plot screen to the source/console screen. I'm seeking to revert the settings back to the default layout where all panes are displayed together in their respective positions.

I attempted to resolve the issue independently by exploring and adjusting various settings in the global options, but unfortunately, none of them proved effective. At this point, I've exhausted all possible solutions and feel utterly hopeless.